# How many users can use a XML-file read/write without causing problems

Tags: c#, .net, xml, database

I'm using some XML-files and text-files to store my data for a private project, it's me and one more person who uses the applicaiton and it works fine. The reason why I'm not using a SQL-database isn't that relavant I think so over to the question.

I always use **lock(object) {}** when reading and writing to my files to avoid read/write problems.

The question, how many users could I hypothetical have calling to functions that want to read and write to the files before getting performance issues and/or errors in different ways, and what issues would I get?

If anyone have tried this with several users or more, please answer, I'm really interested in knowing :)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
Each lock lasts for 1 to 2 ms.

Comment: As it stands this question is way too broad for Stack Overflow. If you can narrow it down to a specific issue you are facing then it might be OK. You could also try a slightly narrower question at [programmers.se] where we deal with design/whiteboard type questions (among others)

Comment: all depends on how long you keep the file locked as other requests may time out.

Comment: I made an edit with the length of each lock

Comment: Yeah I guess it's more of a theoretical question. Mayby a bad place to ask here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Object locking doesn't lock file access. If you have two separate processes running the same application then they have separate locks. Locking in one process doesn't block the other process.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that each user is running the application on their own computer and accessing an xml-file on a shared drive, then you should use the file locking mecanism not the object locking.
You can open a file for read and write with Share none.

E.g.:

```
bool success = false;
while (!success)
{
    try
    {
        using(Stream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            // Read current content from file.
            // Make changes
            // Save new content to file.
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        // Someone else was modifying the file.
        // Apart from the message (in different languages) there is no way to tell
        // if it was a sharing violation or another IO exception.
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you in your quest.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is using DBE or create your own, which can load data into RAM and manage concurrent access.